# Entity Framework Core using stored procedure to delete entity with bool return

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

I have an entity, lets just call it "Entity", that I want to delete with a stored procedure. The "Entity" entity is relatively complex with a lot of related entities - Hence why, I want to use a stored procedure to delete the Entity.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spDeleteEntity
    @EntityId int,
    @ServiceResult bit output
AS
BEGIN
.... Delete logic here ...
IF @@ERROR = 0
    SET @ServiceResult = 1
ELSE SET @ServiceResult = 0
END
```

As you can see, the stored procedure takes in an `EntityId` for the entity, performs my delete logic, and returns a bit - Which in this case is my `ServiceResult`. Here the `ServiceResult` is "True"/1 if no errors occur while executing the query, and "False"/0 if errors occur. The problem is now, that I want to be able to execute this stored procedure from .NET Core. My Initial idea was to do something like this

```
public bool DeleteEntity(Entity Entity)
{
    return _context.Entity.FromSqlRaw<bool>("spDeleteEntity {0}", Entity.Id);
}
```

I believe this doesn't work, because Entity Framework Core does not know what datatype it should expect. From what I can read, Entity Framework Core only accepts types of `TEntity`. So my question really is, how do I call a stored procedure with Entity Framework Core, so that I can pass an Id and get a bool value returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While in your case, you could simply `RAISERROR` in your procedure to indicate failure.;

```cs
try{
    _context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync($"spDeleteEntity {Entity.Id}");
    return true;
}catch(...){
    return false;
}
```

There is a way to pass sql parameters in / out of raw sql commands using EF Core with something like;

```cs
    var entityId = new SqlParameter("@entityId", Entity.Id);
    var result = new SqlParameter("@result", SqlDbType.Bit)
        { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };

    _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("EXEC @result = spDeleteEntity @entityId", entityId, result);

    return (bool)result.Value;
```

Comment: I tried the following with `RAISEERROR` or `THROW` (since `RAISEERROR` has deprecated) - However, nothing happens.. In this case, I wrapped my sql statement inside a try catch block, and added `THROW` in the catch block.. .NET core keeps returning true from `ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Call your stored procedure in the try catch and add your SqlParameter that you want to pass to sp like this :

```
 try
    {

using(var context = new SampleContext())
{
    //Declare storedprocedure parameter
    var Idp = new SqlParameter("@IdParam", "Idp");

    //Call stored procedure(For async call use ExecuteSqlCommandAsync method) 
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC spName @IdParam", Idp);
}

        Return true:
    }

    catch
    {
        Return false;
    }
```

In this way if execution of sp occurred with error, it goes to catch and return false and if not it's return true.

Note: if you declare `raiseerror` in your  storedprocedure, you can generates an error message and send it to your application try catch.
More details about raiseerror :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but hereafter is the solution I'm using together with EFCore 5 :

The stored procedure is using an output

```
CREATE OR ALTER   PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GET_RESULT]
(
    @Param1 int,
    @Result bit OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Do something
    SET @Result = 1    
END
GO
```

Then the c# call is as follow :

```
using System.Data;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;


try
{
    SqlParameter @Param1 = new SqlParameter("@Param1", oneInt);
    SqlParameter @Result = new SqlParameter("@Result", SqlDbType.Bit)
    {
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
        Value = 0,
    };

    await this.context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(
        "EXEC SP_GET_RESULT @Param1, @Result OUTPUT",
        @Param1,
        @Result);

    return (bool)@Result.Value;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ...
}
```

Actually, I'm not sure if the initialization of the output parameter is required.

This can be adapted to any SQL type